# What is the difference between (tilde) ~ and (caret) ^ in Angular

Tags: angular

I have seen this two signs many times in Angular, but I don't know what is the real meaning of these symbols.

If anyone have good knowledge of these please explain

Comment: I think ans is already given https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/7321113

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Comment: If it is related to package.json then the question is not just limited to Angular only.